# find records by an array key in a document

Tags: mongodb

I have some records like this

```
{
  "_id": "test1",
  "friend": {
    "test2": {
      "name": "ax",
      "level": 1,
      "intimacy": 0,
      "status": 0
    },
    "test3": {
      "name": "es",
      "level": 1,
      "intimacy": 0,
      "status": 0
    }
  }
},
{
  "_id": "test2",
  "friend": {
    "test2": {
      "name": "ff",
      "level": 1,
      "intimacy": 0,
      "status": 0
    },
    "test3": {
      "name": "dd",
      "level": 1,
      "intimacy": 0,
      "status": 0
    }
  }
}
```

i need find the node of friend.test2 in the document of _id=test1
i don`t want change the data struct to solve this problem.anyone can help me.
the result maybe like this

```
{
  "test2": {
  "name": "ax",
  "level": 1,
  "intimacy": 0,
  "status": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Then you have problems if you don't want to change the structure. It is also very unclear what you are asking. Where does the data in your result come from?

Comment: If you mean help me, than you have to show what have you done. Otherwise change it to: someone do my job for me.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I did not realize that this sentence will look unfriendly, it's just because stackoverflow have a word limit . I do not know what to write. sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query.

```
db.<coll>.find({ _id:"test1" }, { "friend.test2":1 })
```

Comment: i`m using php. i tried findOne(array("_id"=>'test1','friend.test2'=>1)).it not work.

Comment: The answer is correct, you need to first look for the _id `test1` then do a projection on `friend.test2`. Read python mongo driver documents, look for projection

Comment: Try $collection->find(array("_id"=>"test1"),array("friend.test2"=>true))

Answer (score 0):

In mongo shell you can do this:

```
db.collection.find({_id:"test1"},{"friend.test2":1})
```

and for php you may try something like

```
$collection->find(array("_id"=>"test1"),array("friend.test2"=>true))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working correctly. Tested.

```
$results = $coll->find(array(), array("_id"=>"test1"),array("friend.test2"=> 1));
```

`foreach($results as $test) {
    print_r($test);
}`